# DBF ODBC Driver in Windows Server 2003 x64

Tags: odbc, 64-bit, dbf

The 64 bits version of Windows Server does not came with the ODBC DBF Drivers by default.

Is there a way to get them?
What alternatives exist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm reasonably certain that the FoxPro drivers can read DBF's very well.  I used this driver on Vista 64-bit without any problems, so I suspect it will work with Server 2003 x64.

[FoxPro Driver](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vfoxpro/bb190233.aspx)